# Save timezone to Linux/PHP via code

Tags: php, timezone, settings

Is it possible to set a timezone via code to PHP? Im not talking about the running single script but for all future scripts? (Like in php.ini)

I know of `ini_set("date.timezone", $newTimeZone)` and `date_default_timezone_set($newTimeZone)` but those only seem to set the timezone for the current script.

Maybe i can set the linux systems timezone via PHP ?

Is there a way to set it permanently via code?

Comment: [Modify php.ini file](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php) (change value of `date.timezone`)

Comment: Either do as fusion3k said or if you have some sort of file that is present throughout, throw it in there. I usually place mine in an include that is included throughout the website since it is necessary to communicate with the DB. Just a thought.

Comment: @KyleHawk I do not use a DB, but i have thought about storing the setting in a config file i have, but i would rather just save it directly IF there were a method to do so.

Comment: Gotcha. Just thought I'd suggest :) That's all I got, hope you find your answer bud!